# is there a batch command to visit a url in chrome and hit full-screen of the video?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

It's a regular swf player on the page, and I would like the batch file to full-screen the video (after visiting the link).

Answer (score 0):

Since a batch doesn't recognizes a window, I suggest to do this task you should switch to JScript/VBscript (possible to send keystrokes), if you can.
Otherwise you may use a third party tool like AutoHotKey(a free, open-source utility for Windows) which is capable of sending keystrokes and can be easily used from inside a batch script.